# wired closed -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

[Source:](http://news.yahoo.com/tsarnaev-court-boston-marathon-bombings-045706558.html)

> One of the shots had fractured the base of Tsarnaev's skull, and his attorneys, citing hospital records, said another gunshot "likely caused traumatic brain injury… Damage to the cranial nerves required his left eye be sutured shut; his jaw was **wired closed** and injures to his left ear left him unable to hear on that side."

How do you understand that phrase? His jaw was bandaged that he could not move it, for example, he could not open his mouth?

Comment: Is there something about [the definition of wired](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/wire) that is confusing? *wire verb [T] : to fasten two things together using wire: `She had her jaws wired together so that she wouldn't be able to eat.`*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jaw wiring](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Jaw+Wiring) is a medical procedure that involves using wire and pins to close the jaws and hold them in place, usually while a severe jaw fracture heals.  He definitely could not open his mouth while it was wired, though if someone with wired jaws walked past you on the street, you might not even notice unless they bared their teeth at you.